# Laravel 4, Blade include template from parent directory - dot notation

Tags: php, laravel, syntax, laravel-blade, directory-structure

I have a directory structure as following:

```
views/
-----common.blade.php
-----module1/
----------index.blade.php
```

I have my views path set to module1

I want to access common.blade.php from index.blade.php, however it gives me a blank page.

I have tried  @include('..\common'), @include('/../common'), @include('//..//common'), @include('\..\common'), @include('common')

I understand it uses dot notation, how do I access parent directory in dot notation?

Zain

Comment: It uses dot notation not like files. And as far is I know, all paths are rooted to the Views folder

Comment: Show those views then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like suggested in the comments you need to provide simple, root based path:

```
@include('common')
```

The view paths in `include` are always absolute to the views base directory, `app/views` by default.

You can alter (or add more paths) it in the `app/config/view.php` file:

```
// default
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../views'),
```